# How to make a simple histogram (representing a distribution) in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

Do you know if it's possible to make a simple histogram representing the frequency of all my values divided by ranges (0-5;5-10;10-15;15-20 ...) ?

Exemple:

[image]

Comment: Is Age a calculated metric or directly fetched from data source?

Comment: Age fetched from source for this example but it could be also a calculated metric. Is this makes a real difference ?

Even with a simple data fetched from data source, I couldn't do it.

Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 26):

This may have gotten easier over time, but you shouldn't need to define every bin by hand anymore. If you can edit your data source, you can add a [calculated field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685?hl=en) in Data Studio with a formula like this:

`FLOOR(age/5) * 5`

If you call this field, say, "age_bin", all entries will have a value that's a multiple of 5, with the label (the value of `age_bin`) indicating the bucket's minimum value. For example:

- An age of "4 days" would be in bin `0`, because `FLOOR(4/5)`=0
- An age of "36 days" would be in bin `35`, because `36/5`=7.2, so `FLOOR(7.2)`=7, and `7 * 5` = 35

You can then make a bar plot with "age_bin" as the dimension, and "Record Count" as the metric.

Comment: this works well, except that bins with no data will not be in the plot, i.e. the x-axis will not grow monotonically. any tips for solving this issue?

Comment: just found out that a bubble chart can do that @jimijazz (I used avg on X and count on Y). It's not perfect, but it shows all the values in between gaps.

Answer (score 5):

A way to do it is to create a new field in DataStudio with a formula like this:

```
CASE 
WHEN Age > 0 AND Age <= 5 THEN "bin1"
WHEN Age > 5 AND Age <= 10 THEN "bin2"
WHEN Age > 10 AND Age <= 15 THEN "bin3"
WHEN Age > 15 AND Age <= 20 THEN "bin4"
ELSE "bin5"
END
```

After that, you can create a barchart graph with any variable, like `Age` in this case, as a measurement and the new variable as the dimension to group the data and select count as the representation

Comment: This is good for a a few number of buckets. How about if I wanted to show range of number that extend from 1 to 500 with bin size of 10?
What is the efficient way to do this?

Comment: thanks, its working on the Age, because it is an Dimension in Google Analytics, is there a work around for metric such as Revenue ? I keep getting errors that you cannot mix metrics and dimensions, or that you cannot Re-aggregating metrics is not supported.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to format your data into "bins." You could do something like this:

```
count(CASE WHEN Age > 0 AND Age <= 5 Then 1) AS bin1
count(CASE WHEN Age > 5 AND Age <= 10 Then 1) AS bin2
count(CASE WHEN Age > 10  AND Age <= 15 Then 1) AS bin3
count(CASE WHEN Age > 15 AND Age <= 20 Then 1) AS bin4
```

This is the easiest way to get your data into a histogram-type format, and then select one of the bar charts available in GDS.

Comment: Just tested and it does not work on Google Data Studio. It said that I can't apply another statistical aggregation on my field.

Answer (score 2):

create a new field call it bin value
compute it using integer division e.g. CAST(Age/10 as INTEGER)
use it as group by

Answer (score 1):

You can create a field of switch case
Lets call it histogram_group

```
WHEN Days_Since_First_Touch > 1  AND Days_Since_First_Touch <= 5 THEN "(1_5)"
WHEN Days_Since_First_Touch > 5  AND Days_Since_First_Touch <= 10 THEN (5_10)"
WHEN Days_Since_First_Touch > 10  AND Days_Since_First_Touch <= 20 THEN (10_20)"
```

But if you notice there is a problem to sort the horizontal axe with histogram_group :
In that case the (10_20) will be before (5_10) :(
But I found a cool way to solve it :)
You create anther fake field that return a value

```
WHEN Days_Since_First_Touch > 1  AND Days_Since_First_Touch <= 5 THEN 0.0001;
WHEN Days_Since_First_Touch > 5  AND Days_Since_First_Touch <= 10 THEN 0.0002;
WHEN Days_Since_First_Touch > 10  AND Days_Since_First_Touch <= 20 THEN 0.0003;
```

Lets call it histogram_order
On the chart line with bar, you are choosing the histogram_group as a Dimension, and on the metrics you are adding  histogram_order next to your parameter, but in style make your parameter as a bar and the histogram_order as a line with width none, remove the axe of histogram_order, and you can create a reactangle to cover histogram_order header.

Answer (score 0):

For a dynamic bin size you can do this in SQL:2011 (PostgreSQL, bigquery, MariaDB, SQL Server 2016, etc.):

First you declare the bin size (in years):

```
WITH params (binsize) AS (
    SELECT 5
),
```

Then you use it as a variable as shown:

```
SELECT
    age,
    CONCAT(FLOOR(age / (SELECT binsize FROM params)) * (SELECT binsize FROM params), '-', FLOOR(age / (SELECT binsize FROM params)) * (SELECT binsize FROM params) + (SELECT binsize FROM params)) AS age_bin
    var1,
    var2,
    ...
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the below query on the data studio when you link among firebase, bigquery and data studio;

```
CASE WHEN Days_Since_First_Touch <= 1 THEN "(0_1)"
     WHEN Days_Since_First_Touch > 1  AND Days_Since_First_Touch <= 2 THEN "(1_2)"
     WHEN Days_Since_First_Touch > 2  AND Days_Since_First_Touch <= 3 THEN "(2_3)"
     WHEN Days_Since_First_Touch > 3  AND Days_Since_First_Touch <= 4 THEN "(3_4)"
     WHEN Days_Since_First_Touch > 4  AND Days_Since_First_Touch <= 5 THEN "(4_5)"
     WHEN Days_Since_First_Touch > 5  AND Days_Since_First_Touch <= 6 THEN "(5_6)"
     WHEN Days_Since_First_Touch > 6  AND Days_Since_First_Touch <= 7 THEN "(6_7)"
     WHEN Days_Since_First_Touch > 7  AND Days_Since_First_Touch <= 8 THEN "(7_8)"
     WHEN Days_Since_First_Touch > 8  AND Days_Since_First_Touch <= 9 THEN "(8_9)"
     WHEN Days_Since_First_Touch > 9  AND Days_Since_First_Touch <= 10 THEN "(9_10)"
     WHEN Days_Since_First_Touch > 10 AND Days_Since_First_Touch <= 15 THEN "(10_15)"
     WHEN Days_Since_First_Touch > 15 AND Days_Since_First_Touch <= 20 THEN "(15_20)"
     WHEN Days_Since_First_Touch > 20 AND Days_Since_First_Touch <= 30 THEN " (20_30)"
     WHEN Days Since First Touch > 30 THEN "N (30+)"
ELSE NULL END
```