# How to use Histogram chart by 3rd-party on Google Data Studio

Tags: data-visualization, looker-studio

I have tried to follow instructions from [Nimantha's](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/56887404) answer of how to use Histogram chart by Supermetrics (3rd-party dev) on Google Data Studio. I used the same database, and I expected my chart would display some data after selecting the data dimension and metric, but it still outputting nothing - no data is displayed on the chart.

Am I missing any step behide? How could I get the same data visualization of Nimantha's answer?

**My report w empty chart:**
[image: My report w empty chart]

PS: The selected area is Histogram chart by Supermetrics which isn't displaying any data.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a histogram using the technique explain in this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65893535/159252

I was not able to get Supermetric Histogram to work either; I suspect you need to follow the method explained on the [Supermetric Website](https://support.supermetrics.com/support/solutions/articles/19000117658-how-to-create-a-data-studio-report-with-supermetrics), but that requires you to set up a Supermetric account and connect Supermetric to your data(!)